# Any ideas for a JS circle calendar/flexible gauge?

Tags: javascript, charts, data-visualization

I see lots of JS examples of timelines, but I want to represent data that are continuous/cyclical. What I'd like to do is display 4 "seasons" on a circle, highlighting the part of the circle that the current date applies to, and likely having some interaction/mouseover capability to display more information.

I've attached a simple diagram. I'm a novice coder but have dealt with JS long enough where if I had a general template I could make it work for my purposes.

Does anyone know about a JS script that can support this or what the best way to implement this is? I'm guessing the circle would have to have the dates "mapped" on it, so the dynamic data would be dates, but the script would know what part of the circle corresponds to what date.

I've seen gauges that could do similar things like google gauge from their charts API, but that doesn't have enough flexibility.

Thanks very much! [image: example chart]

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a Javascript pie chart and work from there. d3js is probably your best option.

You can structure your data as follow:

```
Activity,Start,End
Basketball,Jan 1, Mar 31
Tennis, April 1, Aug 24
...
```

Then in the code, convert them to days and feed to Pie chart data to do percentage. Finally, create the label on arc and around pie chart.

Here's an example to start with:

http://vida.io/documents/gSvr8dAH23eirKQDp